# Twilio function event parameter does not contain value. Example: Event.name object is undefined

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

I'm facing an issue where when my twilio funciton is called, when i pass in two function parameters as shown below, they cannot be accessed from within the twilio function. The error says that event.name is undefined. but im passing a parameter called name through the funciton like shown below. So after passing a paremeter like this (edit: here im passing test but its the same output for test as well) :
[image]

I get this output[image]

my code is as below :
[image]

FIXED! Sorry it was totally a problem on my end, I had configured the SMS and the Call for the same number, that was creating a bit of a issue.

Comment: Can you confirm you published your Studio Flow? Button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get back when you log out the entire event object stringified like so; `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`